# Best way to handle sword moving in animation in libGDX

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

So I have a character, I made a rectangle to cover his body for intersections with enemies, so he will get hurt when he intersects an enemy. The problem I am having is, he has a sword, the sword is behind him at an angle, since he is carrying it with him, when the player attacks, the animation is played and the sword swings, over his head and hits down in front of him. I have a polygon that outlines the sword in the idle/run positions, but I can't figure out if it is worth it to try to move the polygon manually during each frame of the attack animation, then check the overlapConvexPolygons through each frame of the animation to see if the sword hit an enemy, or if I should just make the rectangle that covers the body wider to accommodate the sword at the end of the animation, and check to see if that intersects with an enemy, then if it does and the character is attacking, the enemy is hurt and not the character.

It's really hard to explain, and I am hoping it makes sense. Honestly, I am not even sure how I could manually move the polygon during each frame of the animation when the character is attacking. Currently I am using a "GameRenderer" class that handles the "render" method and draws the correct frame to the screen based on what is happening in the game, something like this...

```
public void render() {
    //draw the world and such here.
    batcher.begin(); //batcher is a SpriteBatcher
    Animation<TextureRegion> ani;
    if(character.isAttacking()) {
       ani = AssetLoader.playerAnimations.get("attack");
       batcher.draw(ani.getKeyFrame(character.getRunTime()), character.getX(), character.getY(), character.getWidth(), character.getHeight());

      if(ani.isAnimationFinished(character.getRunTime()) {
        character.setAttacking(false);
      }
    } else if(character.isMoving()) {
       ani = AssetLoader.playerAnimations.get("run");
       //draw running
    } else {
       ani = AssetLoader.playerAnimation.get("idle");
       //draw idle
    }
}
```

Using that, I am not sure how I could update the position of the polygon when the attack animation is running, without doing some sort of switch statement on the current animation frame, which seems a bit much since it will have to get the frame, then run through the possible frames and update the polygon based on the frame number that is running. Not impossible, just doesn't seem like the best way to handle this type of thing. So I'm thinking maybe at the end of the attack animation, I just make the rectangle of his body the full size of the sprite including the sword and check collisions then?

If you need it the rectangle and polygon are created in the character class like so....

```
class Character {
  //all the variables needed
  public final int CHARACTER_HEIGHT = 76;
  public final int CHARACTER_WIDTH = 74; //all measurements are half of sprite size
  //rest of the variables

  public Character(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.centerX = (width / 2);
    this.centerY = (height / 2);
    this.bodyX = Math.round((x + centerX) - (CHARACTER_WIDTH / 2));
    this.bodyY = Math.round((y + centerY) - (CHARACTER_HEIGHT / 2) - 14);
    position = new Vector2(x, y);
    characterBody = new Rectangle();
    sword = new Polygon(new float[] {0, 0, 12, 0, 12, 50, 0, 50});
    sword.setOrigin(30, 50);
    sword.setRotation(-78f);
  }

  public void update(float delta) {
    runTime += delta;
    characterBody.set(bodyX, bodyY, CHARACTER_WIDTH, CHARACTER_HEIGHT);
    sword.setPosition(bodyX + 5, (bodyY - CHARACTER_HEIGTH + 18));
    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta);
  }

  //getters and setters for characterbody, sword, isAttacking, etc
}
```

Hopefully that helps and I am making sense. I am more than happy to provide anything needed to help out with this. I am just really lost and trying to find the best solution to handle how to detect a collision with the sword, and if I should try to update the position and rotation of the sword polygon at each frame of the attack animation, then check collisions, or if I should just expand the rectangle that is the characters body to include the sword when it is swung and check collisions with that.

Thank you, and I apologize for the mess of code and terrible description.

Comment: I actually did that and it looks nice. 
I just create a 2d array with angle,x,y for each frame. (10 frame in total)
and its separated from char sprite. 
Take a look 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kvAFtnwphI

Comment: its easy(and cheap) to check collision with overlap rectangle.No need for a complicated polygon collision check.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell this is a 2D game...

One way that may work:

1. Find the distance between the player and the enemy.
2. If the distance is less than the swing range of the sword then the player has hit the enemy.
3. You would also have to take into account the direction that the player is facing etc.

Another option is to use Box2D and apply forces to a polygon set that is the sword, on a joint and see if it hits something, but that's a whole other answer.